# ngStyle more properties

Tags: angularjs, ng-style, angularjs-ng-style

I want to have more properties in ng-style but it won't work.

This is my code line:

```
<h3 ng-style="{color: titleColor; font-size: titleSize;}">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h3>
```

If I only have the `{color: titleColor}` then it works perfectly.

**Help me to get the font-size in there aswell**

Comment: You need to wrap `font-size` in quotes also remove semi columns and use comma. i.e `{color: titleColor, 'font-size': titleSize}` What you have is invalid syntax. Look at the console about the error.

Comment: Thanks man it works now

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: or camel case fontSize without wrapping in quotes, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<h3 ng-style="{'color': titleColor, 'font-size': titleSize}">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h3>
```